# How to render list with different order from array object in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I get the data from server something like this way:

```
    "cells": [
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available hours",
          "value": 1806,
          "valueMap": "1 806"
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available customer hours",
          "value": 1773.2,
          "valueMap": "1 773,20"
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Absence hours",
          "value": 32.8,
          "valueMap": "32,80"
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available hours project",
          "value": -7092.8,
          "valueMap": "-7 092,80"
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Average price",
          "value": 0,
          "valueMap": "0"
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Agreement hours",
          "value": 8866,
          "valueMap": "8 866"
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Utilization agreements %",
          "value": 500,
          "valueMap": "500"
        }
      ]
```

Now, if I render a list this way:

```
<template v-for="(cell, index) in cells">
   <li>
      {{ cell.consultingBudgetHeadName }}
   </li>
</template>
```

It will show the output this way:

- Available hours
- Available customer hours
- Absence hours
- Available hours project
- Average price
- Agreement hours
- Utilization agreements %

But I need the order in a different way than the order of the array. I want my order will be like this:

- Available hours
- Absence hours
- Available customer hours
- Agreement hours
- Available hours project
- Average price
- Utilization agreements %

So, instead of dynamic rendering, I took the index of the array element and render the element this way:

```
<ul v-for="(row, rowIndex) in data.rows">
   <li>{{ row.cells[0].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
   <li>{{ row.cells[2].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
   <li>{{ row.cells[1].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
   <li>{{ row.cells[5].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
   <li>{{ row.cells[3].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
   <li>{{ row.cells[4].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
   <li>{{ row.cells[6].consultingBudgetHeadName }}</li>
</ul>
```

But I don't think this would be a good idea as index number can be changed at the database any time. So, what's the good way to achieve those?

**[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-custom-ordering-table-forked-574t6o?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)**

Comment: Do you want to print `consultingBudgetHeadName` field or `value` field in cells array?

Comment: `valueMap`. I used `consultingBudgetHeadName` in the post as simplicity so that it will be understandable.

Comment: "as index number can be changed at the database any time" not a good idea to not name columns then. There should be some kind of id for them in server response

Comment: There is id (`consultingBudgetHeadId`) by the way: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-custom-ordering-table-forked-574t6o?file=/src/assets/data.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your array and return it sorted with computed property:

```js
const mappedCells = new Map([["Available hours", 1], ["Available customer hours", 3], ["Absence hours", 2], ["Available hours project", 5], ["Average price", 6], ["Agreement hours", 4], ["Utilization agreements %", 7]])
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      "cells": [{"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available hours", "value": 1806, "valueMap": "1 806"}, {"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available customer hours", "value": 1773.2, "valueMap": "1 773,20"}, {"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Absence hours", "value": 32.8, "valueMap": "32,80"}, {"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available hours project", "value": -7092.8, "valueMap": "-7 092,80"},  {"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Average price", "value": 0, "valueMap": "0"}, {"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Agreement hours", "value": 8866, "valueMap": "8 866"}, {"consultingBudgetHeadName": "Utilization agreements %", "value": 500, "valueMap": "500"}]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sortedCells() {
      return this.cells.map(c => {
        c.nr = mappedCells.get(c.consultingBudgetHeadName)
        return c
      }).sort((a, b) => (a.nr > b.nr) ? 1 : -1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <li v-for="(cell, i) in sortedCells" :key="i">
      {{ cell.consultingBudgetHeadName }}
   </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks neat solution. The array object I used in the post is 1D. But, in my actual scenario (i.e. in the CodeSandbox Demo), it's nested (inside another array Object `rows`). That won't be an issue hopefully. I will try implement your solution. May be, I need: `this.data.rows.map(a => a.cells.map())`?

Comment: @user1896653 hey mate, you are right, access your array and map it. But if you have access to the back-end better solution will be to set order number there, so less work on the front :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is to have an extra field in the database for `index` of the item, and then in the front end when you retrieve the data you can sort the list according to that field.

For example

```
 "cells": [
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available hours",
          "value": 1806,
          "valueMap": "1 806",
          "order": 1,
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available customer hours",
          "value": 1773.2,
          "valueMap": "1 773,20",
          "order": 3,
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Absence hours",
          "value": 32.8,
          "valueMap": "32,80",
          "order": 2,
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Available hours project",
          "value": -7092.8,
          "valueMap": "-7 092,80",
          "order": 6,
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Average price",
          "value": 0,
          "valueMap": "0",
          "order": 4,
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Agreement hours",
          "value": 8866,
          "valueMap": "8 866",
          "order": 5,
        },
        {
          "consultingBudgetHeadName": "Utilization agreements %",
          "value": 500,
          "valueMap": "500",
          "order": 7,
        }
      ]
```

Then set a computed property for the sorted cells.

```
computed: {
  sortedCells() {
     return this.cells.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, That can be a way. Do you have any examples of that? For example a dataset with order/index number. And then sort the list based on that?

Comment: @user1896653 Yes, I just update the answer, please check again.

Comment: Thanks, I got your idea

Answer (score 0):

You can put your list of sorted keys in an array and v-for over that instead.

```
<div v-for="a in all">
  <div v-for="key in presortedListOfKeys">
    {{a[key]}}
  </div>
</div>
```